# In Python, within a string, remove multiple spaces with a single space, if it's not leading multi spaces

Tags: python, regex

I have various strings that might have multiple leading spaces.

```
string_1 = '    param A     val A'
string_2 = 'param B    val B'

....
```

I want to replace all multiple spaces with a single space IF the  multiple spaces are not in the start of the string.

I want output of above to become

```
 string_1 = '    param A val A'z
 string_2 = 'param B val B'
```

My current solution replaces all multiple spaces with a single space regardless.

```
 re.sub('\s+',' ',s)
```

How would I construct a pattern that only captures non leading multiple spaces?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\b\s{2,}\b` as your pattern, If those multiple spaces are leading, they are not in a word boundary. Also for multiple spaces use `{2,}` instead of `+` to exclude single space:

```py
import re


string_1 = "    param A     val A"
string_2 = "param B    val B"


pattern = re.compile(r"\b\s{2,}\b")
for test in (string_1, string_2):
    print(pattern.sub(" ", test))
```

output:

```
    param A val A
param B val B
```

**Note**: Trailing multiple spaces is not changed this way. To do that you can omit last `\b` then if converts to a single space again.

---

As noted by @JvdV, `\b` doesn't take other range of characters into account. For example if you a string like `"[    param A     val A    ]"`, the above pattern won't work for it. Instead you can use a *Positive Look Behind* assertion (`(?<=\S)`) and *Positive Look Ahead* assertion (`(?=\S)`) to match any non-white-space character:

```py
>>> import re
>>> text = "[    param A     val A    ]"
>>> re.sub(r"\b\s{2,}\b", " ", text)
'[    param A val A    ]'
>>> re.sub(r"(?<=\S)\s{2,}(?=\S)", " ", text)
'[ param A val A ]'
```

Comment: + but a small note: `\b` will not recognize any characters other than `\w`.

Comment: @JvdV Thanks for mentioning. Updated accordingly.

Comment: There should not be a `(?=\S)` assertion at all because the OP does not say that trailing spaces should not be replaced. `{2,}` is greedy so `(?<=\S)\s{2,}` will do.

Answer (score 3):

Have a go with:

```
(?<=\S)\s+(\s\S|$)
```

And replace with `\1`. See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ydqblu/1)

---

- `(?<=\S)` - Assert position is preceded by a non-whitespace char;
- `\s+` - 1+ Whitespace char (greedy);
- `(\s\S|$)` - Capture group to match a whitespace char and a non-whitespace char ***or*** a end-string anchor.

---

The above will leave only leading spaces alone. For example:

```
import regex as re
s = '    Abc   12$   D   Efg    '
print(re.sub(r'(?<=\S)\s+(\s\S|$)', '\1', s))
```

Prints:     `Abc 12$ D Efg`

Answer (score 0):

split your input into two groups (1st group: leading space, 2nd group: everything else), then eliminate the multispaces from 2nd group, and join groups:

```
>>> string_1 = '    param A     val A'
>>> sb = re.compile(r'^(\s+)(.*)')
>>> mg = sb.match(string_1).groups()
>>> mg[0] + ' '.join(mg[1].split())
'    param A val A'
```